# How to get a c# program i made to work on another pc?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010 to write a program that will need to be run on multiple computers. So far I can run the program on another pc if the pc has VS 2010 installed on it. If there is no VS 2010, then the program doesn't run. Is there a way to get the program to run without having to install VS 2010?

Comment: You should make an installer (MSI) or manually install the .NET Framework version you require on client machines. You should include what the error message is when you attempt to run your program.

Comment: The problem is there the PC's do not contain .NET Framework installed or the version installed is out of date (installed: .NET 2.0, Program needs a 4.0). Download the .NET Framework and install on the machines.
link to download .NET Framewor 4.0 => http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Comment: I figured it was a framework issue. I just figured I'd throw out the question before I got too involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right click your project and go into the properties, take a look at the `Application` tab, you can see what the target framework is:

[image: target framework]

This indicates what the minimum version of .NET framework is required to run your application. As long as you have .NET framework with that version or higher installed on your other machine, your program will run.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need just .NET Client Profile to be installed on another computer. Just check which version you use. I think it's .NET 4 if you use VS 2010.

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=24872)